# Перебор массива для группы пользователей на сайте PHP

Tags: php

ув. Знатоки, помогите с перебором массивом группы пользователей на сайте.

Нужно сделать условие которое будет относиться к одной из групп которые указаны номером в массиве.

Сделал так:

```
$nice_status = array(1, 2, 3, 5, 10);

for($i=0; $i<count($nice_status); $i++) {
if($user['group']==$nice_status[$i]) { 
// echo ...
}
}
```

Но так выполняется только один раз. 
Если использовать данный код в выборке из бд создавая таблицу пользователей.

Comment: `Но так выполняется только один раз. Если использовать данный код в выборке из бд создавая таблицу пользователей.` - Проясните этот момент

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$nice_status = array(1, 2, 3, 5, 10);

if (in_array($user['group'], $nice_status)) {
    // echo ...
}
```

P.S. А для выборки из БД используйте `WHERE`